# How to configure Tycho to Build Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

The screenshot below is "Installation Deatils" of "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqq99.png)

Such as "Wild Web Developer XML tools" , it appears in two places. How can I configure my project and tycho to build my custom RCP like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is far too broad, read a tutorial such as [this one](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) The Eclipse build is just a feature based RCP product

Comment: I tried it but still don't know where the problem is.
In the ".product" file , if I include a feature A without  installMode="root" , I can get the result like the former in the screenshot.
 if I include a feature A with  installMode="root" , I can get the result like the latter in the screenshot.
How can I get both at the same time ? Thank you.

Comment: @greg-449 , hello , could you give me some more advice , Thanks a lot.